# Blender 2.8 Circular dependency error when baking textures

Tags: texture-baking

I have a corridor. The corridor is made up of 2 pieces, a side, and a body(for testing purposes). The side and the body each have one material I UV unwrapped and then made visible in the EEVEE render through the node editor. After that, I have created a new UV map, and I also created a new image with the default settings. Following that, I switched from eevee to cycles because eevee doesn't have the bake option. What followed is a messed up texture bake, and an error reading out "Circular dependency error for cube.001 . I've read that I must disconnect the nodes of materials from the tree, but I did not understand which ones. I looked through a dozen videos and forum posts but couldn't figure it out, perhaps because I am a total noob as of right now. 
[image]

So I've disconnected the node that is on the right, since I thought that it is what was specified in some forums. But what is resulted(just as I suspected) is a white bake that does not contain my two textures that I tried to bake.

[image]

I am close to the right answer however I am stuck. What do I need to do so I can remove all materials and then use a single one with the baked texture on it? Thank you in advance.

---

Alright, I figured this out! Hell yeah! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9airvjDaVh4

Answer (score 18):

Just disconnect the TEXTURE node you are baking to. Then reconnect after it is finished baking. HTH.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Do you know why this is necessary?

Comment: I also dont get why it is made this complicated and easy-to-forget..

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, and just figured out how to fix it.  What the issue was was that I had separated one of my mesh layers into separate mesh layers, and each one of these retained duplicate copies of my materials.  After I deleted the unnecessary duplicate materials on those other mesh layers, it baked just fine.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the UV-Map to the destination image.

You find the *UV-Map Node* in the *Shader Editor* under *Add -> Input -> UV Map*. Then you have to connect the purple UV socket to the *Vector* socket of you destination image.

Double check if you have selected the correct UV-Map and file in every material.

After that backing should work without any circular dependencies.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but whoever else might have this issue, maybe I can offer some help. I had 3 separate materials on my mesh. I had to add the image texture node I was baking to each of these materials and made sure they were each selected.

[image]

Added to each

[image]