# How to Bake Textures with a UV map that is too large

Tags: uv, export, texture-baking, baking

I'm rather new to blender and am attempting to bake textures (using cycles) I made and applied onto a model in order to export it to Unity. However, many of these textures require the uv map to be significantly larger than the 500x500 square blender gives me. The black box is approximately the size of the UV square:
[image: The black box is approximately the size of the 500x500 UV Map square]

I know I can create another UV Map, but just like resizing, this ruins how I want the textures to look. Also, it may be related, but blender is kicking me these errors:

[image]

I'm rather new and its the first thing I've worked on so heavily texture focused. What should I do to fix this? Do I need to remap and make every material so it fits in the square?

Comment: I dont think I understood your issue ... UVmap is a position of vertices in U and V coordinates. You can scale it up or down. Also what is 500x500 square that blender gives you? ... you can set image size in dimension you need (even 50.000 x 50.000 px). Your UVmap screen overlaps a ton of faces that is totaly wrong for single texture. Also all unwrap algorythms try to generate maps free of empty space between parts, so you have other parts not visible now or someone manipulated with maps already (or deleted some parts of mesh so like that it would be huge waste of space without new unwrap.

Comment: Circular dependency ... you can search ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/139554/2214